# ERROR: column "g.start_date" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
select *
FROM player_game_stats pgs INNER JOIN games g ON pgs.game_id = g.id where pgs.player_id=265
and (g.part_of_season='REGULAR' or g.part_of_season='BUBBLE') order by start_date desc limit 10;
```

gives me 10 rows of the data i want

however

```
select avg(points)
FROM player_game_stats pgs INNER JOIN games g ON pgs.game_id = g.id where pgs.player_id=265
and (g.part_of_season='REGULAR' or g.part_of_season='BUBBLE') order by start_date desc limit 10;
```

gives me a sql error of ERROR: column "g.start_date" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

why is this a problem and how can i solve it?

Comment: Which tables contains the `points` column?

Comment: Why do you want to order if you're only getting a single value?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name table player_game_stats contains points and table games contains start_date

Comment: As mentioned already, your AVG() query without a GROUP BY will return 1 row only. No need to use ORDER BY.

Comment: @HoneyBadger i want it in the order of start date, take the top 10, and then avg those numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I want it in the order of start date, take the top 10, and then avg those numbers*

You need a derived table to do that:

```
select avg(points)
from (
  select pgs.points
  FROM player_game_stats pgs 
    JOIN games g ON pgs.game_id = g.id 
  where pgs.player_id=265
    and g.part_of_season IN ('REGULAR', 'BUBBLE') 
  order by start_date desc 
  limit 10
) t;
```